# Oracle SQL TO_CHAR Function return values

Tags: sql, oracle, function, to-char

I don't understand why these two code results are identically the same? I thought if I have quotes it just concatenate strings. Why not first one is 300.5100? I know second one is 400.5 anyway. Thank you

```
Select to_char('300.5' + '100') From Dual;

Select to_char(300.5 + 100) From Dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

To concatenate strings in SQL you have to use `||`.  The `+` is only there to add numbers. If you didn't pass `'300.5' + '100'` you would simply get an error, e.g. the following is invalid SQL:

```
select '300.5' + '100'
from dual;
```

But as `to_char()` expects a number as the input parameter Oracle implicitly converts those strings to numbers and then adds them, just like in the second statement.

Answer (score 3):

concatenation is

```
'xxx' || 'yyy'
```

your example allows the literals to be converted to numeric then treated as normal numbers.